# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: objective-c, pointers, ios

Okay, I am having a hard time with this. I've searched for the past hour on it and I don't get what I am doing wrong. I'm trying to take the currentTitle of a sender, then convert it to an integer    so I can use it in a call to list.

```
NSString *str = [sender currentTitle];
NSInteger *nt = [str integerValue]; // this is where the error appears //
NSString *nextScreen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Screen_%@.jpg", [screenList objectAtIndex:nt]];
```

I assume it's something with the `[str integerValue]` bit not being properly used, but I can't find an example that works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's analyze the error message:

***Initialization (`NSInteger nt`) makes pointer (`*`) from integer (`[str integerValue]`) without a cast.***

This means that you are trying to assign a variable of non-pointer type (`[str integerValue]`, which returns an `NSInteger`) to a variable *of* pointer type. (`NSInteger *`).

Get rid of the `*` after `NSInteger` and you should be okay:

```
NSString *str = [sender currentTitle];
NSInteger nt = [str integerValue]; // this is where the error appears //
NSString *nextScreen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Screen_%@.jpg", [screenList objectAtIndex:nt]];
```

[`NSInteger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html) is a type wrapper for the machine-dependent integral data type, which is defined like so:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: This is correct. Perhaps one of the things users transitioning from an all object platform get confused by most.

Comment: Thanks so much for this fast answer. That did the trick and your breakdown helped me understand the "why" much faster!

Comment: @Eric You are very welcome. That's what StackOverflow is for! :)