# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So my code is this

```
int theTime = [timeEnter.text intValue];
```

Why does that return the error?

*initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast*

Thanks.

Comment: Something must be up with timeEnter.text, try changing it to a clean string and try.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187488/initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSInteger theTime = [timeEnter.text intValue];
```

If this doesn't work, check out the text and make sure it really is an integer e.g. write it to the console with

```
NSLog(@"%@",timeEnter.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing, it works fine, just make sure that you have an integer value in the timeEnter.text (I'm guessing it's a textbox)