# Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: objective-c

I declare "extern NSDate *chooseDate" in my "global.h" file.  I include this file in my "blueview" and in blueview I add the line "NSDate *chooseDate = YES".  I get the warning message as shown in the title.  I have read up on this, and I understand that the warning is saying that I am trying to assign an object to an integer.  The part I don't get is that I am declaring chooseDate as an NSDate in both files.  I don't understand how either is an integer.  The funny part is that my program works correctly, I am just trying to get rid of this warning.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `YES` is an integer (1). You get a warning for assigning an integer to an object variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187488/initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're reading the error backwards: It says you're trying to assign an **integer** to an **object** variable. So you're correct that the variable is an object pointer, but `YES` is not a pointer to an NSDate object, it is a BOOL value (which is a kind of integer).

Comment: You know, sometimes the answer is so easy you don't see it.  I just removed the "YES" and the warning is no more.  Thanks.