# Another "Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I know there's already plenty of threads that start off this way.  I'm reading that most of them are attempting to assign a value of type int to an NSInteger which I can understand is going to throw an error.  However, I don't think that that's what I'm doing this time.

What I'm trying to do is get the value of the selectedSegmentIndex of a UISegmentedControl and then store that in an NSInteger variable.  According to the UISegmentedControl Class Reference this property is an NSInteger as well.

> selectedSegmentIndex The index number
>   identifying the selected segment (that
>   is, the last segment touched).
>
> @property(nonatomic) NSInteger
>   selectedSegmentIndex

So here's the code:

```
- (IBAction) continueClick:(id)sender {
    NSInteger *playerCount = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];

    GameController.numberOfPlayers = playerCount;
}
```

Pretty simple and basic.  As far as I can tell anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187488/initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187488/initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `*` so that `playerCount` is an `NSInteger` and not a pointer to an `NSInteger`:

```
NSInteger playerCount = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];
```

`NSInteger` is a numeric type and not a class.

Comment: Fair enough. I've added that information to the answer. Thanks for that!  Feel free to edit the answer yourself if you'd like to further expand or clarify. Or, if you'd prefer, go ahead and write up your own answer. Either way. The main thing, of course, is to get the best possible answer one way or another.