# Initialization makes pointer from integer without cast

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuinteger

i got this warning when i try to get a character at index

Initialization makes pointer from integer without cast

here's the code :

```
int random(arch4random()%(string.length));
NSString * char =[string charachterAtIndex:random];
```

i just wanna 
Thanks

Comment: Oh, and anyway, you shouldn't use `char` as a variable name. It's a primitive type from c.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187488/initialization-makes-pointer-from-integer-without-a-cast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Is the method. It returns a unichar, not an NSString. You are declaring your variable is an NSString pointer but a unichar is stored as an integer behind the scenes.

Your line should be

```
unichar character = [string charachterAtIndex:random];
```

as a side note you can't call your variable char as its a reserved keyword in C.

Answer (score 0):

[NSString characterAtIndex] returns a character, not a string object.  So you can't assign it to a NSString named char (or named anything else).    You can say:

```
unichar ch = [string characterAtIndex:random];
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the compiler is warning that by writing

```
NSString * name = [string characterAtIndex:random];
```

you're storing a pointer to a NSString * to the address referred by the character returned (unsigned long).
If you need to have the resulting character as a NSString, you should use a method like

```
[NSString substringWithRange: NSRangeFromString([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d-%d", random, 1])];
```

which returns a pointer to an NSString object.